# Tomcat 8.5 , showing 404 error after deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I developed a web application by using Spring and Hibernate framework and deployed to tomcat v.8.5. It was deployed and running fine. But next day, when I opening the URL its showing 404 error. The server is up all time, and only one application is deployed. Manager application is running without any problem,[! it showing my application status is running. Am I missing any configuration or what?

in log file showing (localhost_access_log.2017-09-20).
 192.168.2.213 - - [20/Sep/2017:08:44:01 +0300] "GET /ecom_demo/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1006

[image]

Comment: Add the catalina file .

Comment: @RajaRamachandran I didn't change anything in Catalina file, it has the default value when install time. You meant was Catalina.policy and catalina.properties files, is it?

Comment: Catalina is a log file.